# JPEG compress PHP image to memory

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple site for our local Boy Scout troop, which should allow image upload.
I'm using PHP 4.3.9 to resize the images and create thumbnails, but the (donated) hosting service
does not allow file system writes from PHP. They do, however, provide 5G of mysql. I would like to
store the images in the database, but have not found a way to convert the resized images to JPEG. As far as i can tell, imagejpg will only write to a file (which i can't do). Does
anyone know if it is possible to generate a JPEG to memory in PHP?
Thanks!
-jim

Comment: Oh maan.... I know, you don't look a gift horse in the mouth etc. etc., but PHP web hosting that doesn't allow writing *files*? That is terribly silly. Also, 4.3.9 is a *very* old version and no longer supported. I would consider switching to a decent hosting package if at all possible.

Comment: php4 has been dead for a long time, it's high time you upgraded to at least 5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

To clarify, if you look at the [manual for imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), you'll see that you can use it to either write to a file or output the raw image stream directly, depending on the second parameter. I am using output buffering to capture that raw image stream.

Comment: To clarify: imagejpeg() does not only write to files, it can also display the image to standard output. This answer explains how to capture such output.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario You're right, I'll add a small explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I saw imagejpeg's raw output option, but thought that would only stream back to the browser. Was completely unaware of output buffering!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the output buffering solution by jeroen, but I'll add this as a cool alternative.

Use the class from here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php

```
class VariableStream {
    var $position;
    var $varname;

    function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        $url = parse_url($path);
        $this->varname = $url["host"];
        $this->position = 0;

        return true;
    }

    function stream_read($count)
    {
        $ret = substr($GLOBALS[$this->varname], $this->position, $count);
        $this->position += strlen($ret);
        return $ret;
    }

    function stream_write($data)
    {
        $left = substr($GLOBALS[$this->varname], 0, $this->position);
        $right = substr($GLOBALS[$this->varname], $this->position + strlen($data));
        $GLOBALS[$this->varname] = $left . $data . $right;
        $this->position += strlen($data);
        return strlen($data);
    }

    function stream_tell()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function stream_eof()
    {
        return $this->position >= strlen($GLOBALS[$this->varname]);
    }

    function stream_seek($offset, $whence)
    {
        switch ($whence) {
            case SEEK_SET:
                if ($offset < strlen($GLOBALS[$this->varname]) && $offset >= 0) {
                     $this->position = $offset;
                     return true;
                } else {
                     return false;
                }
                break;

            case SEEK_CUR:
                if ($offset >= 0) {
                     $this->position += $offset;
                     return true;
                } else {
                     return false;
                }
                break;

            case SEEK_END:
                if (strlen($GLOBALS[$this->varname]) + $offset >= 0) {
                     $this->position = strlen($GLOBALS[$this->varname]) + $offset;
                     return true;
                } else {
                     return false;
                }
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    function stream_metadata($path, $option, $var) 
    {
        if($option == STREAM_META_TOUCH) {
            $url = parse_url($path);
            $varname = $url["host"];
            if(!isset($GLOBALS[$varname])) {
                $GLOBALS[$varname] = '';
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do

```
stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream")
    or die("Failed to register protocol");

$GLOBALS['binaryImageContent'] = '';
imagejpg($im, 'var://binaryImageContent');
$data = $GLOBALS['binaryImageContent'];
echo strlen($data);
```

Comment: Thanks! Cool technique, plus it gives me some more exposure to what can be done in PHP. (i'm actually a C/C++ developer; never touched PHP before taking on the troop's site).

Answer (score 0):

You could "generate to memory" but I don't see how you plan to store the image for later retrieval.  If you plan to just resize the image every time someone loads the page, you'll be burning a lot of CPU time.  Since there is no option to write directly to disk (really?) let me suggest instead that you at least store the image as BLOB in the MySQL database.  Though this is inefficient and not good practice either, it is still better than doing the same work over and over and over again each time the page is refreshed.

More generally, I suggest dumping the "donated" provider and getting a real web service.  Nearly every web hosting company provides some flavor of MySQL and PHP.  For shared hosting with light usage you could probably get away with something for $10 - $20 / month.  PHP 4.3.9 was released in 2004.  It's going to be tough finding good documentation for that particular version and you can't ignore the number of bug fixes made since then.

Comment: I think he's planning to save the image as a BLOB into the database, that's why  he needs to capture imagejpeg's output. But I agree with the rest (about dumping the provider)

Comment: Eh. As long as i can get a simple site up and running, $0/month beats $10/month ($120 per year --> selling an extra 30 bags of popcorn! ;-) ) And, yep, the images are going into the database.